# access control-intersection of subjects’ permissions

Tags: access-control, operating-systems

In the book named "**operating system security**", I read this paragraph:

> "Protection domains can also be constructed from an intersection of
>   the associated subjects (e.g., Windows 2000 Restricted Contexts
>   [303]). The reason to use an intersection of subjects permissions is
>   to restrict the protection domain to permissions shared by all, rather
>   than giving the protection domain subjects extra permissions that they
>   would not normally possess."

I don't understand the meaning of "**intersection of subjects permissions**" and how to use this property.Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

The author is being vague, but *may* be trying to express the idea of a protection domain that is accessible by two or more persons, without creating a new permission that the persons share.

Assume it exists and has permissions (joe, rw-) (sam r--) and (bob rw-)  If we can also set the permission (~[joe|sam|bob] ---) then we have an unnamed security-domain-like-thing that only they can access.

I would
1. see if that description is consistent with the other descriptions in the chapter/section, and consider
2. writing the author and asking them (:-))